# Intercept button refresh on flutter web

Tags: flutter

I would like to be able to control when the user reloads the page, either with F5, cmd + r, or with the native button of the browser, how can I intercept that button to modify it.

I need to change the main function of the update action in flutter web

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.